# Generating landscape cards with Squib

Tags: squib

How do I make landscape cards?

Here is the deck:

```
Squib::Deck.new(cards: 1, layout: 'layouts/landscape.yml') do
  background color: 'white'

  rect layout: 'cut'
  rect layout: 'safe'

  save format: :png, prefix: 'landscape_'
end
```

And the layout:

```
cut:
  x: 37.5
  y: 37.5
  width: 1050
  height: 750

safe:
  x: 75
  y: 75
  width: 975
  height: 675
  radius: 16
  dash: 3 3
```

The output appears cut off:
[image: Example output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the width and height options of the `Squib::Deck.new` function.

http://squib.readthedocs.io/en/v0.14.0/dsl/deck.html

```
Squib::Deck.new(cards: 1, width: 1125, height: 825, layout: 'layouts/landscape.yml') do
  background color: 'white'

  rect layout: 'cut'
  rect layout: 'safe'

  save format: :png, prefix: 'landscape_'
end
```